# How to correctly define constants in C++

Tags: c++

I see a common pattern in many C++ codebases:

Header.h:

```
static const int myConstant = 1;
```

Source1.cpp:

```
#include "Header.h"
```

Source2.cpp:

```
#include "Header.h"
```

Based on:

> 3.5 Program and linkage

...

> (2.1) — When a name has external linkage , the entity it denotes can be referred to by names from scopes of
>   other translation units or from other scopes of the same translation unit.
>
> (2.2) — When a name has internal linkage , the entity it denotes can be referred to by names from other scopes
>   in the same translation unit.

...

> 3 A name having namespace scope (3.3.6) has internal linkage if it is the name of
>
> (3.1) — a variable, function or function template that is explicitly declared static; or,

`myConstant` is accessible only from the same translation unit and the compiler will generate multiple instances of it, one for each translation unit that included `Header.h`.

Is my understanding correct - multiple instances of `myConstant` are created? If this is the case can you please point me to better alternatives of using constants in C++

EDIT:

Some suggested to make `myConstant` `extern` in the header and define it in one `cpp` file. Is this a good practice? I **guess** this will make the value invisible to the compiler and prevent many optimizations, for example when the value appears in arithmetic operations.

Comment: How about marking it `constexpr`? Compiler would probably optimize it away then.

Comment: Why not use the preprocessors #define for this?

Comment: @Veda It's considered a bad practice. It's the other way round. Use `const` in place of `#define` whenever possible.

Comment: `const` variables were always treated in C++ as constant expressions unless their odr-use required otherwise (such as taking their address). If you use them only as true constants even the `static` qualifier is not needed.

Answer (score 4):

What you're doing should be fine. The optimizer will probably avoid creating any storage for the constants, and will instead replace any uses of it with the value, as long as you never take the address of the variable (e.g. `&myConstant`).

Answer (score 1):

A pattern `static const int myConstant = 1` arising in header files is a little bit strange, because keyword `static` restricts the scope of a variable definition to the specific translation unit. Hence, this variable can then not be accessed from other translation units. So I don't see why someone might expose a variable in a header file though this variable can never be addressed from "outside".

Note that if different translation units include the header, then each translation unit will define *its own*, somewhat "private" instance of this variable.

I think that the common pattern should be:

In the header file:

```
extern const int myConstant;
```

In exactly *one* implementation file of the whole program:

```
const int myConstant = 1;
```

The comments say, however, that this will prevent the compiler from optimisations, as the value of the constant is not know at the time a translation unit is compiled (and this sounds reasonable).

So it seems that "global/shared" constants are not possible and that one might have to live with the - somewhat contradicting - keyword `static` in a header file.

Additionally, I'd use `constexr` to indicate a compile time constant (though the compiler might derive this anyway):

```
 static constexpr int x = 1;
```

Because the `static`-keyword still disturbs me somehow, I did some research and experiments on `constexpr` without a `static` keyword but with an `extern` keyword. Unfortunately, an `extern constexpr` still requires an initialisation (which makes it a definition then and leads to duplicate symbol errors). Interestingly , at least with my compiler, I can actually define `constexpr int x = 1` in different translation units without introducing a compiler/linker error. But I do not find a support for this behaviour in the standard. But defining `constexpr int x = 1` in a header file is even more curious than `static constexpr int x = 1`.

So - many words, few findings. I think `static constexpr int x = 1` is the best choice.

Comment: Please see my edit, I think the value won't be visible to the compiler in this case.

Comment: Unless the address of `myConstant` is taken (or some other tricky odr-use) there probably won't be any variable.

Comment: @StoryTeller I think the compiler HAS to create a variable if you use extern. The name has to be accessible from anywhere (it might be in a library).

Comment: Its the keyword `const` which lets the compiler do a lot of optimisations;  It will probably not define a variable at all.

Comment: @Felics - If you use `extern` it's a different matter. You shouldn't for compile time constants.

Comment: @StoryTeller this is what this answer suggests - use `extern` in the header and define it in one translation unit...

Comment: @Felics - Apologies. My original comment was about the formulation of the answer at *"Note that if different translation units include the header, then each translation unit will define its own, somewhat "private" instance of this variable."* While I assumed you were speaking in general. This answer only applies to run-time constants. And then you have to be careful of the static initialization order fiasco.

Comment: @StephanLechner - The compiler can't avoid creating a variable here. Separate compilation of translation units may require it. The linker *may* eliminate it, but I wouldn't count on it. And then there's the SIOF to consider if the constant is used before main is entered.

Comment: @StoryTeller: right; adapted by answer. Spent some time concerning an `extern constexpr`-usage but did not come to a useful end.